# A Question Regarding the Relation Between Second-Order Arithmetic and the Constructible Universe

Tags: set-theory

Colin McLarty, in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/111361/13653), writes,

> Simpson's book Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic shows $Z_2$ can interpret some fragments of ZF strong enough to give good theories of constructible sets...."

What is the 'best' theory of constructible sets ('best'= largest fragment of the constructible universe) $Z_2$ is able to 'give'?

Also, a related question. In a review of Simpson's book, one reviewer claimed that the second-order arithmetic Simpson used was a 'many-sorted first-order theory'.  If this is in fact the case it seems that at first glance (by definition of the constructible hierarchy itself) that all of $Z_2$ (many-sorted) can be interpreted in ZF+V=L.  If one construes $Z_2$ as an actual second-order theory, can all of $Z_2$ (actual) be interpreted in $L^2$ (second-order constructibility as defined in Myhill and Scott's paper "Ordinal Definability") and does this produce different results than in the many-sorted first-order case?

Comment: Could I ask the reasons for the downvotes?

Comment: A downvote seems a bit harsh to me, but maybe someone wants you to use MathJax and linebreaks.  The question is a bit hard to read as it is.

Comment: @Trevor:  Is there a tutorial on MathJax offered here?

Comment: There is (it's harder to find than it should be): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Trevor: I have attempted to use MathJax to improve formatting.  If one types \Z_2\ and \L^2\ (as I have done), shouldn't the subscripts and superscripts automatically appear?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: MathJax (LaTeX) should be delimited by `$...$`.

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks for the help.